# In Spring Social Tweeter, how does JSON become a Tweet, and how does RestTemplate.getObject<T> work?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-social-twitter

everybody.

In **Spring Social Twitter** we use `RestTemplate.getObject<T>()` to retrieve and deserialize data from the REST endpoint. It does its job and it is very neat! But **how does it do that?**

How can the JSON (source 1) be translated into the .JAVA (source 2).

- Source 1: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets
- Source 2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/blob/master/spring-social-twitter/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/Tweet.java

*This question has come up when I noticed that "coordinates" is inside TweetData, not as an attribute of Tweet.*

Thanks for the help in advance!

**EDIT**
I found out the class that does the deserialization and the answer and posted it up thanks to Mr. @Sotirios Delimanolis hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Sotirios Delimanolis, I digged around to find how the **`HttpMessageConverter`** worked. And the **`HttpMessageConverter`** is in fact used by most of the deserialization in the *Spring Social Twitter* api.

However, for Tweets (whose JSON varies a lot from the Tweet.java structure), I have found that we use an object called **`TweetDeserializer.java`** (self explainable, right?)

**The aswer, therefore, lies here:**

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-twitter/blob/master/spring-social-twitter/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/twitter/api/impl/TweetDeserializer.java

**Craig Walls** describes it in the file docs:

> Custom Jackson deserializer for tweets. Tweets can't be simply mapped
>   like other Twitter model objects because the JSON structure varies
>   between the search API and the timeline API. This deserializer
>   determine which structure is in play and creates a tweet from it.
>   @author Craig Walls

I'm sorry for bothering you guys with this silly question, but I feel that pushing this answer up here might help people landing in Spring development to find their way around.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses a collection of [`HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) instances to convert request or response body content to a custom type. For JSON content types, Spring has [`MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) and [`GsonHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.html) (depending on your version).

Assuming you meant [`RestTemplate#getForObject`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#getForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-), you specify a target type as `Class` argument. Spring will pass that target type to the appropriate converter and perform deserialization.

Comment: Hm, thanks very  much @sotirios-delimanolis! I will dig around and check it.